# How to get the html of an input checkbox with jquery or javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This is what I have in html file

```html
 <label><input type="checkbox" id="abc-news-au" /> ABC News (AU)</label><br />
    <label><input type="checkbox" id="ars-technica" /> Ars Technica</label><br />
    <label><input type="checkbox" id="associated-press" /> Associated Press</label><br />
```

I want to get the text between labels Ex. ABC NEWs (AU)

I use the following code but didnt work *(v is the id of the element)

```
console.log("get text: "+ $("#"+v).text()) //(empty)
console.log("get text: "+ $("#"+v).html()) //undefined
```

The only code that shows something is

```
console.log("get text: "+ v) //abc-news-au
```

which is obviously the id of the element...
How do I get the text of the element?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `$("#"+v).parent().text()` to get what you want.
This is because the text is inside `<label>` node, not `<input>` node.

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/epL3tkza/

Comment: Thanks!! it solves the problem. However, the <label> in "setting.html" and the code I need to write is in "index.html". I noticed that when the page is at "index.html" it will prints nothing. Only prints when I am already located in "setting.html". Is there any way to solve this?

Comment: @Joey This is expected. In "index.html" you can only select nodes within "index.html", not in other html file, like "setting.html". I'm not sure if I understand your problem though.

Comment: Yes that's what I'm trying to solve. is there any method that I can use to work around this?

Comment: I don't know a way to work around. Maybe other people can answer, or you may open another question for this new problem.

Answer (score 1):

`<input />` does not have any `html()` or `text()`. It's a self closing tag. You want to get the `.text()` of it's wrapping `<label>`.

Using `jQuery`:

```js
$('body').on('click','input', function(e){
  console.log($(e.target).closest('label').text());
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label><input type="checkbox" id="abc-news-au" /> ABC News (AU)</label><br />
<label><input type="checkbox" id="ars-technica" /> Ars Technica</label><br />
<label><input type="checkbox" id="associated-press" /> Associated Press</label><br />
```

Answer (score -1):

> I want to get the text between labels Ex. ABC NEWs (AU)

you could use the DOM node **[`nextSibling`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_node_nextsibling.asp)** property, example:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label><input type="checkbox" id="abc-news-au" /> ABC News (AU)</label><br />
<label><input type="checkbox" id="ars-technica" /> Ars Technica</label><br />
<label><input type="checkbox" id="associated-press" /> Associated Press</label><br />

<script>
 $('input[type=checkbox]').click(function (e) {
     if($(this).is(':checked')) {
         var data = this.nextSibling.nodeValue;
         console.log(data);
     }
 });
</script>

</body>
</html>
```